# Вывести большее по модулю

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Даны два целых числа. Вывести большее по модулю из них.
        Что не так?

```
var
a, b, c, d: integer;
 begin
readln(a, b);
c := a mod 2;
d := b mod 2;
if c >= d then writeln(a)
        else writeln(b)
end.
```

Comment: [Модуль числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joks, Вас сбило с толку название оператора получения остатка от деления: mod, и Вы в Вашем случае получаете на самом деле остаток от целочисленного деления на 2, а не модуль числа. Два парных оператора div и mod  используются для целочисленного деления - для получения частного и остатка.

Так, например,  13 div 2 = 6, а 13 mod 2 = 1 (Целое частное при делении 13-ти на 2 = 6, а остаток при этом делении =1)

В Вашем же случае, чтобы получить модуль числа необходимо использовать ф-цию abs(...)
Таким образом Ваша программа должна выглядеть так:

```
program BiggestByMod;
var 
  a,b : integer;
begin
  ReadLn(a,b);
  if abs(a) >= abs(b)
    then WriteLn(a)
    else WriteLn(b);
end.
```

Тогда, если на входе, например: 11 -27

То на выходе: -27